# Sharepoint 2013 calendar - only current user and people with events

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, calendar, sharepoint-calendar

Is it possible to create default view of SP calendar that will be able to show current logged user and people with events like "absense"

Answer (score 1):

You can try to create a view and filter on Attendees = [ME]

[image]

Comment: Ok, but I also need to see other user events l- only their absenses ( not only mine).

Comment: you can add another condition to the Filter using OR to show you more

Comment: But i guess it isin't possible to create filter that will show automaticlt me  and other users with events. If I'm wrong please correct me.[link](http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-RchiWDtGF5w/TZJfJIMvafI/AAAAAAAABV0/iR6DPca-Ryg/s1600/Screen+shot+2011-03-29+at+3.36.46+PM.png) like these